# Parse HTML string into array

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, diff-lcs

I'm developing a wiki-like difference functionality for bodies of HTML produced by TinyMCE. `diff-lcs` is a difference gem that accepts arrays or objects. Most difference tasks are on code and just compare lines. A difference on bodies of HTML ridden text is more complex. If I just plug in the bodies of text, I get a character by character comparison. Although the output would be correct, it would look like garbage.

```
seq1 = "<p>Here is a paragraph. A sentence with <strong>bold text</strong>.</p><p>The second paragraph.</p>"

seq2 = seq1.gsub(/[.!?]/, '\0|').split('|')
=> ["<p>Here is a paragraph.", " A sentence with <strong>bold text</strong>.", "</p><p>The second paragraph.", "</p>"]
```

If someone changes the second paragraph, the difference output involves the previous paragraphs end tag. I can't just use `strip_tags` because I'd like to keep formatting on the compare view. The ideal comparison is one based on complete sentences, with HTML separated out.

```
seq2.NokogiriMagic
=> ["<p>", "Here is a paragraph.", " A sentence with ", "<strong>", "bold text", "</strong>", ".", "</p>", "<p>", "The second paragraph.", "</p>"]
```

I found plenty of neat Nokogiri methods but nothing I've found does the above.

Comment: Nokogiri is designed to parse XML/HTML, so the starting point you have of `seq2`, an array of strings, is not an appropriate use of Nokogiri. What's the full output of TinyMCE? Is there a root element?

Comment: The output from TinyMCE is similar to seq1. seq2 isn't important, I'd just like to get to something with a format like seq3. It looks like I'll have to parse the Nokogiri object for children, then do something like seq2.

Comment: You can use the SAX interface and append every tag to an array, and for Text nodes, split on words.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SAX, could you elaborate?

Comment: How big are your HTML files? DOM parsing, which is the defacto way of parsing HTML with Nokogiri, is much easier. The benefit is the entire file is parsed and in memory so you can restructure the HTML, or jump around in it. The downside is it's all in memory. I rarely see a HTML file that won't fit into memory, otherwise it wouldn't fit into a browser either. SAX only allows linear processing of the markup, but doesn't pull it into memory, so huge files, typically XML, can be handled. See http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/HTML/SAX.html for more information.

Comment: It's actually just a fragment. Just what's in a db cell which is put there by publishing using TinyMCE. I've posted an answer but open to suggestions on how to do it better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you could do it with a [SAX parser](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/SAX.html):

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'

html = "<p>Here is a paragraph. A sentence with <strong>bold text</strong>.</p><p>The second paragraph.</p>"

class ArraySplitParser < Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document
  attr_reader :array
  def initialize; @array = []; end
  def start_element(name, attrs=[])
    tag = "<" + name
    attrs.each { |k,v| tag += " #{k}=\"#{v}\"" }
    @array << tag + ">"
  end
  def end_element(name); @array << "</#{name}>"; end
  def characters(str); @array += str.gsub(/\s/, '\0|').split('|'); end
end

parser = ArraySplitParser.new
Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Parser.new(parser).parse(html)
puts parser.array.inspect
# ["<p>", "Here ", "is ", "a ", "paragraph. ", "A ", "sentence ", "with ", "<strong>", "bold ", "text", "</strong>", ".", "</p>"]
```

Note that you'll have to wrap your HTML in a root element so that the XML parser doesn't miss the second paragraph in your example.  Something like this should work:

```ruby
# ...
Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Parser.new(parser).parse('<x>' + html + '</x>')
# ...
puts parser.array[1..-2]
# ["<p>", "Here ", "is ", "a ", "paragraph. ", "A ", "sentence ", "with ", "<strong>", "bold ", "text", "</strong>", ".", "</p>", "<p>", "The ", "second ", "paragraph.", "</p>"]
```

**[Edit]** Updated to demonstrate how to retain element attributes in the "start_element" method.

Comment: Any ideas what I could add to `ArraySplitParser` to preserve tag attributes?

Comment: @Archonic Hint: look at the parameters to the `start_element` method. The parser passes in an `attrs` variable.

Comment: I've updated the answer. It was parsing the attrs but not writing them to `@array`.

Comment: I'm back at this. Any idea how to handle images in this?

Answer (score 2):

You're not writing your code in idiomatic Ruby. We don't use mixed upper/lower case in variable names, also, in programming in general, it's a good idea to use mnemonic variable names for clarity. Refactoring your code to be more how I'd write it:

```
tags = %w[p ol ul li h6 h5 h4 h3 h2 h1 em strong i b table thead tbody th tr td]
# Deconstruct HTML body 1
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(@versionOne.body)
nodes = doc.css(tags.join(', '))

# Reconstruct HTML body 1 into comparable array
output = []
nodes.each do |node|

  output << [
    "<#{ node.name }",
    node.attributes.map { |param| '%s="%s"' % [param.name, param.value] }.join(' '),
    '>'
  ].join

  output << node.children.to_s.gsub(/[\s.!?]/, '|\0|').split('|').flatten

  output << "</#{ node.name }>"

end

# Same deal for nokoOutput2

sdiff = Diff::LCS.sdiff(nokoOutput2.flatten, output.flatten)
```

The line:

```
tag | " #{ param.name }=\"#{ param.value }\" "
```

in your code isn't Ruby at all because String doesn't have a `|` operator. Did you add the `|` operator to your code and not show that definition?

A problem I see is:

```
output << node.children.to_s.gsub(/[\s.!?]/, '|\0|').split('|').flatten
```

Many of the tags you are looking for can contain other tags in your list:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table><tr><td>
      <table><tr><td>
        foo
      </td></tr></table>
    </td></tr></table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Creating a recursive method that handles:

```
node.attributes.map { |param| '%s="%s"' % [param.name, param.value] }.join(' '),
```

would probably improve your output. This is untested but is the general idea:

```
def dump_node(node)

  output = [
    "<#{ node.name }",
    node.attributes.map { |param| '%s="%s"' % [param.name, param.value] }.join(' '),
    '>'
  ].join

  output += node.children.map{ |n| dump_node(n) }

  output << "</#{ node.name }>"

end
```

Comment: Thanks! This is all great to know. Am I right in thinking @maerics answer with the sax parser circumvents the need to recursively dump nodes?

Comment: SAX, by its nature, sees each tag serially, which lends itself to outputting the nodes the same way. As a result, for this purpose, it avoids the need to recursively dump nodes. See my comment to the original question about the pluses/minuses of SAX vs. DOM.